# Почему while не ждем завершения функции с puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Код скрипта:

```js
(async () => {

  while(1) {
    let test = await goPage(url);
    
    console.log(test);
    
    //сразу же выдает undefined хоть и видно что браузер еще открыт и там производятся заданные действия...
  }
  
  
})();


async function goPage(url) {
  ....
  
  return result;
}
```

test сразу же выдает undefined хоть и видно что браузер еще открыт и там производятся заданные действия...

Comment: очевидно же, что проблема где-то в goPage. я отредактировал ваш snippet чтобы и вам это стало очевидно

Comment: @nörbörnën не надо придумывать код за автора, вы таким образом вводите в заблуждение меня и других пользователей